# Can't add Foreign Key in MySQL with identical columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, each with a `provider` column:

```
CREATE TABLE `title` (
  `provider` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,

CREATE TABLE `notification` (
  `provider` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
```

However, when I try and add a foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE notification ADD FOREIGN KEY (provider) REFERENCES title (provider)
```

I get the following obscure error:

```
Can't create table 'metadata.#sql-c91_345b' (errno: 150)
```

Both of the tables are empty. Why is this occurring and what do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Try making `provider` a primary key before adding a foreign key referencing it.

Comment: Is it because there's another primary key? I'm curious if you could link up to the real PK in this case.

Comment: I do have an auto-increment pk id here, but even when I dropped that column (and had no primary key) I was running into the same error.

Comment: Could you use title's autoincrement integer PK instead of a varchar(40) one? I think MySQL used to require a unique index on the target column (i.e. title's provider) to exist; it may have changed in the later versions, but it's worth trying to see if it helps.

Comment: Aren't you accidentally using the `MyISAM` engine instead of `InnoDB`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html says:

> InnoDB requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan.
>
> In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.
>
> Such an index is created on the referencing table automatically if it
>   does not exist.
>
> (This is in contrast to some older versions, in which indexes had to
>   be created explicitly or the creation of foreign key constraints would
>   fail.) index_name, if given, is used as described previously.

I think you should create any (unique, primary, or plain) index for `title.provider` before creating a foreign key pointing to it.

Answer (score 1):

Run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` and look at the "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR" to see more details on the error.